# Returning the number of rows affected by an indicator in SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've created a tablix which has a column for a due date.  I've also implemented an indicator which does one of two things.  If the due date <= current date, the indicator shows a green check mark, otherwise a red x.  I want to count the number of rows that're affected by the "green check mark" indicator.  How would I approach doing this?

Sorry if this seems like a trivial question, I'm fairly new to SQL Server Report Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.  Put this where you want your count to be:

=SUM(IIF(due date <= current date,1,0))